# How to download .xlsx file from server?

Tags: c#, .net

In my App_Data folder I added test.xlsx file. What I want to do is to make possible for user to download it.
So in my Controller I have a method `DownloadSample`:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage DownloadSample()
    {
        var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        var filePath = GetFilePath();
        byte[] excelData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        var result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(excelData);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "test.xlsx"
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
        return result;
    }
```

and in my Angular service:

```
  public GetSample(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.pathToController}/DownloadSample`, { responseType: "blob" });
  }
```

I am able to download the file, but the problem is when I open it:

> We found a problem with some content in "test.xlsx". Do you want
> us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of
> this workbook, click Yes.

In Network tab, as response I can see weird characters:
[image]

What could be missing here? Any ideas?

Comment: MS Office documents are `.zip` files, the first two bytes are `PK`.... I would suggest comparing the source and downloaded files. Are they the same length? Has any character conversion occurred? ...